# Why doesn't this @font-face style apply to my HTML?

Tags: css, font-face, blueprint-css

I am hoping someone can please point out what's not working about this font-face implementation.  I've testing this using the body tag so there's no question as to whether the issue is with the HTML (yes, I do have a body tag.)

I have obtained the fonts and the implementation CSS from FontSquirrel.  Thanks for looking at this!

CSS:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'DymaxionScriptRegular';
    src: url('DymaxionScript-webfont.eot');
    src: url('DymaxionScript-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('DymaxionScript-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('DymaxionScript-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('DymaxionScript-webfont.svg#DymaxionScriptRegular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

body {
    font-family: DymaxionScriptRegular, courier;
}
```

File tree structure:

[image: Screenshot of my development folder showing location of CSS, index.html and font files.]

Screenshot of Courier fallback font:

[image: Courier fallback font]

**Answer**: Apparently if one leaves "Regular" off of the font-family declaration, everything works fine. Answered my own question by playing with it.

**Real Answer**: My first "answer" only worked in Safari. What worked in all of them was changing "'DymaxionScript-webfont..." to '../DymaxionScript-webfont... After I did that, everything worked. It was bad pathing.

Comment: I'd use Charles or Firebug net panel to see if the request is even being made for the font and if it's 404'ing.

Comment: Also what browser are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a more concise @font-face implementation, that I know works across the board:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'DymaxionScriptRegular';
    src: url('/path/to/font/webfont.eot?') format('eot'),
         url('/path/to/font/webfont.woff') format('woff'), 
         url('/path/to/font/webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('/path/to/font/webfont.svg#webfont') format('svg');
    font-weight:normal;
    font-style:normal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For various web fonts you can check out google.com/webfonts which has a bunch of different fonts for use, but you just add a link to google's site and it will return the proper formatting for most browsers as far back as ie6

Answer (score -1):

@font-face {

```
font-family: 'DymaxionScriptRegular';
src: url('webfont.eot');
src: url('webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('webfont.svg#webfont') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
```

}

body {
    font-family: DymaxionScriptRegular, courier;
}

Comment: He got rid of the "dymaxionscriptregular" from the URLs and changed it to "webfont" for the last part of the SVG URL. Not sure why, though. @sayed - It's a good idea to also have an explanation for what you suggest.